# Using isset() inside a foreach doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Basically, I have an indefinite number of buttons that I want to generate from variables held in the mysql database.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM array');
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($array as $var) {
echo '<br>Would you like to accept or reject?';
echo '<br><input name="accept' . $var['subject'] . '" type="submit" value="Accept" /><input name="reject' . $var['subject'] . '" type="submit" value="Reject" />';
}
```

Now when I try to press the buttons nothing happens. This is the code I thought might work for that:

```
foreach ($array as $var) {
$accept = 'accept' . $var['subject'];
$reject = 'reject' . $var['subject'];
if (isset($_POST[$accept])) {
//script for accept
}
if (isset($_POST[$reject])) {
//script for reject
}
}
```

There are no errors. I think it's because I can't use isset inside a foreach this way. Is there some other efficient way of doing what I am trying to do here?

Comment: you use the 2nd script when you submit the form?, are you creating a form in the 1st script?

Comment: check your `$accept`, `print_r($_POST)`, *I bet you forget to run sql query before second loop*

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: Jeff got it. I omitted the <form> tags.

Comment: why not use array function instead of loop ..? also check var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error was because I forgot to use <form> tags in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can and it will work fine but you will probably want to change it to the following

```
if (!empty($_POST[$accept])) {
    //script
}

if (!empty($_POST[$reject])) {
    // script
}
```

`$_POST` is a global variable and is always ogoing to be seen as 'set' is the issue.

Comment: Erm... Just because `$_POST` is set doesn't mean that `$_POST['motorcycle']['torpedo']['boat']` is.